# No path for AVR Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have just installed the eclipse AVR Plugin, followed the download issues here: 
http://avr-eclipse.sourceforge.net

But the AVR Header files are not valid, in AVR Path settings:
[image]

Where can I find these Paths?
(runs on Win 10 64bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer. You should install WinAVR, it includes the GNU GCC compiler for C and C++.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/winavr/

You can also find a good manual here:

http://avr-eclipse.sourceforge.net/user%20manual/tasks/task_path_preferences.html

Aftre intalling this tool, eclipse recognise the path automatically (or you must select it).